# Can a sample space itself contain empty sets, or does it?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given the definition: The sample space $\Omega$ is the set of all possible outcomes of an experiment.

I just wonder can the $\emptyset$ be an 'outcome' of an experiment, which may refer to the situation where 'nothing happens' or 'not known'. Or are we assuming that there must be an outcome so this situation is prohibited by the assumption?

Also, I am aware that $\Omega \neq \emptyset$, since if so, the Axiom $P(\Omega) = 1$ indicates that $P(\emptyset) = 1$, but $P(\emptyset)$ can't be $1$, or $P(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i})$ diverges for $A_i = \emptyset, \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$ thus violating the Axiom of unit total measure. Is this fact helpful in constructing an argument against the attempt to put $\emptyset$ in $\Omega$?

Comment: The empty set is a subset of $\Omega$, but the empty set is not an element of $\Omega$. In an other words, the empty set is an event but it is not an outcome.

Comment: Your explanation works for me in terms of logic, but it confuses me how an object being a subset of a set, but in the meantime, not an element of that set. Is there a definition for experiment outcome that helps explain the situation? @littleO

Comment: You could say the set of irrational numbers is a subset of the set of real numbers, but you would not say it was an element of the real numbers; by contrast the set of irrational numbers is an element of the power set of the real numbers.   Similarly the empty set is a subset of $\Omega$ but not an element of $\Omega$, so it is not an outcome; the empty set is an element of the sigma algebra $\mathcal F$ in your probability space, and so is an event (an event which never happens).

Comment: $\emptyset$ is always a **subset** of $\Omega$ and so is always an event.  $\emptyset$ is *commonly not* an **element** of $\Omega$, however there is nothing explicitly stopping it from being an element in exactly the same way that nothing is explicitly stopping $0$ or $1$ from being elements.  Take for instance the experiment of throwing labeled balls at a box, possibly landing in or not landing in the box.  Let the outcomes of the experiment be the set of balls who successfully landed in the box.  $\emptyset$ is a perfectly valid *outcome* to this experiment corresponding to no balls in.

Comment: Do not confuse $\Pr(\emptyset)$ which must always be zero with $\Pr(\{\emptyset\})$ which might or might not be zero.  These are different things.  $\emptyset$ is a different object than $\{\emptyset\}$.  On the left, $\emptyset$ is a zero element set.  On the right, $\{\emptyset\}$ is a one-element set... it is the set who contains the element "$\emptyset$."  You can think of it as "*depth*" being important.  $\Pr(\emptyset)$ is the probability of none of the possible outcomes occurring and is zero.  $\Pr(\{\emptyset\})$ is the probability that the outcome $\emptyset$ occurred.

Answer (score 2):

You should think measure theory ( without it you cant define probabilities) what you need is :  $\Omega$ is a set (collection of possible outcomes), you equip it with a sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ ( which is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ ), only then can you define your probability measure on the $\textit{measurable space}$ $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$.

The empty set wont be an element of $\Omega$, it will be an element of the sigma-algebra! Just have a read of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Definition_and_properties and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space